# Can CPU load data from another CPU's cache using LOCK CMPXCHG instruction in x86?

Tags: x86, cpu-architecture, atomic, cpu-cache, mesi

Let's say we have CPU-X and CPU-Y which have their own L1d caches. First, on CPU-X we execute simple read operation on memory location `M` that is stored in DRAM: after that CPU-X loads value stored in `M` into its own L1d cache and put it into (E) state (assume it uses MESI protocol for cache coherency).

Then CPU-Y execute `lock cmpxchg` on the same memory location `M`. According to *Intel 9.1.4. "Effects of a LOCK Operation on Internal Processor Caches"* section:

> For the P6 and more recent processor families, if the area of memory being locked during a LOCK operation is
> cached in the processor that is performing the LOCK operation as write-back memory and is completely contained
> in a cache line, the processor may not assert the LOCK# signal on the bus. Instead, it will modify the memory location internally and allow it’s cache coherency mechanism to ensure that the operation is carried out atomically. This
> operation is called “cache locking.”

So, since the value of `M` isn't cached in CPU-Y's caches, it must assert the LOCK# signal on the bus, right? Then, will it load value stored in CPU-X's caches into its own L1d cache (or something else happen?)? If so, must CPU-X put its own value into (I) state?

Comment: No, it doesn't use LOCK. CPU-Y just uses the cache coherency protocol to obtain exclusive access to the line and then modifies the line in its cache. CPU-X has to give up the line.

Comment: IIUC, `CPU-X` must put its cache line into (I) state, and once `cmpxchg` is done `CPU-Y`'s cache line will be in (M) state, right? Then, e.g. if `CPU-X` execute `lock cmpxchg` on the same memory location `CPU-Y` must give up its cache line (put it into (I) state) and then `CPU-X` will have its cache line in (M) state containing modified value of `M` location, right? This is going to be cache ping-ponging?

Comment: Your understanding of MESI is correct. This will result in cache-line bouncing (never heard that referred to as ping-ponging, but sure, why not). However, The lock signal is only used if the operation spans two cache-lines due to misalignment (a.k.a. [split locks](https://lwn.net/Articles/790464/)) or on memory that is not write-back, e.g. uncached DMA memory

Comment: @Homer512: FYI, I've heard the term "ping pong" before to describe a cache line forced to bounce between cores, especially in false or true sharing situations.  Google has 2.15 million hits for [cache line ping pong](https://www.google.com/search?q=cache+line+ping+pong), including some titles of journal articles, a masters thesis, and an IBM tuning guide (https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/hot-cache-lines-false-sharing-cache-line-ping-ponging-and-performance).  TL:DR: it's not too obscure.

Comment: Related: [Is incrementing an int effectively atomic in specific cases?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39393850) and [LOCK prefix vs MESI protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29880015) re: the fact that `lock add` on WB cacheable memory can just take a bus lock, holding MESI exclusive ownership of the cache line by not replying to share or invalidate requests between the load and the store parts of a `lock add` or `lock cmpxchg`.  Intel's vol.2 manual describes it in a simplistic way that doesn't match the performance of real CPUs: multiple cores can be atomic-RMWing diff cache lines at once.